# Select only the bottom continuous rows where specific value is present Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this data frame

```
lst = [['A',1],['B',0],['C',1],['D',0],['E',1],['F',1],['G',1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = ['name','val'])
```

Looks like this

```
  name  val
0    A    1
1    B    0
2    C    1
3    D    0
4    E    1
5    F    1
6    G    1
```

I want to get the rows where `val` is 1 but they should be bottom continuous rows.

Desired output

```
  name  val
4    E    1
5    F    1
6    G    1
```

I am doing, which will give all val with 1.

```
df[df.val == 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to get the last block:

```
# blocks separated by `0`
s = df.val.ne(1).cumsum()

# last blocks and only value 1
df[s.eq(s.max()) & df['val'].eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
  name  val
4    E    1
5    F    1
6    G    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by taking the bit difference and seeing the last time it goes from 0 to 1, and using that as an index to the array.

```py
df.iloc[(df.val.diff().drop_duplicates(keep='last') == 1)
           .idxmax():]
```

Output:

```py
  name  val
4    E    1
5    F    1
6    G    1
```